# Matrix mod 2 multiplication

Tags: circuit-construction

There was a similar question asked [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/quantum-addition-and-modulo-operation-using-gates), but I feel like mine is even more basic.

What's the easiest way to implement a circuit $U$ corresponding to a matrix-vector multiplication modulo 2?

$$
|x_1x_2x_3\ldots x_n\rangle \mapsto |y_1y_2y_3\ldots y_n\rangle=U|x_1x_2x_3\ldots x_n\rangle
$$
where
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \ldots \\ y_n
\end{pmatrix}
= M
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \ldots \\ x_n
\end{pmatrix} \mod 2 \ .
$$
Matrix $M$ entries are $0$ and $1$, the multiplication is done modulo 2.

**UPDATE**

The optimal solution in given  [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/123782/95710).

For a simple solution see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my question is given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs6Td.png). The solution from the provided paper is extremely efficient (for it requires $O(n^2 / \log n)$ CNOTs instead of the naïve $O(n^2)$ estimate), and is somewhat nontrivial to implement.

An easy-to-implement solution with $O(n^2)$ CNOTs can be, however, obtained in just a few lines. First of all, one has to perform the LU-decomposition of the desired matrix $M$. This can be done as follows:

```
P, L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(M)
L = np.mod(L, 2)
U = np.mod(U, 2)
```

Luckily, for an invertible matrix $M$, the resulting $P,L,U$ matrices will contain binary entries. Here $P$ is a permutation matrix, and $L$ and $U$ are the lower- and upper-triangular matrices, whose product is the original matrix, $M = P \ L \ U$.

Permutations $P$ can be implemented using SWAPs. Multiplication by a triangular matrix is also quite straightforward, and is done using CNOTs **starting from the most occupied row**. In other words, for $U$ one should start from the first row: once the first qubit is calculated, it is never used in the following calculation, and so on. If you, say, wanted to transform qubits according to
$$
M
\begin{pmatrix}
q_0 \\ q_1 \\ q_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_0 \\ q_1 \\ q_2
\end{pmatrix} \ ,
$$

the circuit would look like

[image]

A typical scenario in which one may need to implement such a matrix transformation on qubit registers arises in quantum simulation. Namely, in order to encode a state of a fermionic system using the Bravyi-Kitaev encoding, one needs to perform a matrix transformation of the original qubit registers (which can equivalently be thought of as being Jordan-Wigner encoded).

Interestingly enough, the Bravyi-Kitaev encoder matrix is lower-triangular from the very beginning [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5986), so in this particular case there is no need to perform the LU-decomposition.